# View Rendering Error

Tags: mvc

I am new to sitecore. I am stuck in one issue. While browsing to a new sitecore item created like `http://sc92/newpage` I am getting the below error.

> Error Rendering View: \Views\Layouts\Website\Default.cshtml: Error while rendering view: '\Views\Layouts\Website\Default' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').Inner Exception: The partial view '\Views\Layouts\Website\Default' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched: ~/Views/Sitecore/\Views\Layouts\Website\Default.cshtml ~/Views/Sitecore/\Views\Layouts\Website\Default.vbhtml ~/Views/Shared/\Views\Layouts\Website\Default.cshtml ~/Views/Shared/\Views\Layouts\Website\Default.vbhtml ~/Views/Sitecore/\Views\Layouts\Website\Default.aspx ~/Views/Sitecore/\Views\Layouts\Website\Default.ascx ~/Views/Shared/\Views\Layouts\Website\Default.aspx ~/Views/Shared/\Views\Layouts\Website\Default.ascx ~/views/renderers/\Views\Layouts\Website\Default.vbhtml ~/views/renderers/\Views\Layouts\Website\Default.cshtml

I have checked the default view in www.root, it's there inside `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc92\Views\Layouts\Website`. What else I am missing?

Comment: What is the `Path` value of the layout item in sitecore?

Comment: You can try below solution: Copy the respective cshtml file into web/Views folder

Comment: You can try below solution: Copy the respective cshtml file into website/Views folder

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you used backslash characters ** in `Path` field of your layout.

You should use forward slash characters instead */*.

So your path field should be `/Views/Layouts/Website/Default.cshtml`:

[image]